# How do I iterate through the column of a pandas dataframe and delete rows accordingly? (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, jupyter-notebook

This is the dataframe I'm working with right now:

|  | Season | Team | W | L | W/L% | Coaches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-21 | Atlanta Hawks* | 41 | 31 | 0.569 | L. Pierce (14-20) N. McMillan (27-11) |
| 2 | 2019-20 | Atlanta Hawks | 20 | 47 | 0.299 | L. Pierce (20-47) |
| 3 | 2018-19 | Atlanta Hawks | 29 | 53 | 0.354 | L. Pierce (29-53) |
| 4 | 2017-18 | Atlanta Hawks | 24 | 58 | 0.293 | M. Budenholzer (24-58) |
| 5 | 2016-17 | Atlanta Hawks* | 43 | 39 | 0.524 | M. Budenholzer (43-39) |
| 6 | 2015-16 | Atlanta Hawks* | 48 | 34 | 0.585 | M. Budenholzer (48-34) |
| 7 | 2014-15 | Atlanta Hawks* | 60 | 22 | 0.732 | M. Budenholzer (60-22) |
| 8 | 2013-14 | Atlanta Hawks* | 38 | 44 | 0.463 | M. Budenholzer (38-44) |
| 9 | 2012-13 | Atlanta Hawks* | 44 | 38 | 0.537 | L. Drew (44-38) |
| 10 | 2011-12 | Atlanta Hawks* | 40 | 26 | 0.606 | L. Drew (40-26) |
| 11 | 2010-11 | Atlanta Hawks* | 44 | 38 | 0.537 | L. Drew (44-38) |
| 12 | 2009-10 | Atlanta Hawks* | 53 | 29 | 0.646 | M. Woodson (53-29) |

I basically want to only have rows where the Coach's name is different from one year to the next. So for example, I would keep Row 4 since its immediately adjacent row Row 3 has a different name under 'Coaches' column, but I would delete Row 5, 6, and 7 because the name in the 'Coaches' column is the same for all three rows. But, I would want to keep Row 8, because Row 9 (adjacent Row) has a different name in 'Coaches.'

I have gotten this dataframe from reading a csv file
`df = pd.read_csv("hawks.csv")`
and I think I am supposed to call `df.iloc` but I don't know how to iterate through each row and compare the values in the column. So far I have only managed to print the string values in the 'Coaches' column like this:

```
coaches = df.iloc[0:, 7]
for name in coaches:
    print(name)
```

But I want to know how to obtain the value stored in the 'Coaches' column when I iterate through each row (and then delete rows that do not fit the criteria I am looking for). Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the column by comparing consecutive rows with `shift`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [ { "idx": 1, "Season": "2020-21", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks*", "W": 41, "L": 31, "Coaches": "L. Pierce (14-20) N. McMillan (27-11)" }, { "idx": 2, "Season": "2019-20", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks", "W": 20, "L": 47, "Coaches": "L. Pierce (20-47)" }, { "idx": 3, "Season": "2018-19", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks", "W": 29, "L": 53, "Coaches": "L. Pierce (29-53)" }, { "idx": 4, "Season": "2017-18", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks", "W": 24, "L": 58, "Coaches": "M. Budenholzer (24-58)" }, { "idx": 5, "Season": "2016-17", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks*", "W": 43, "L": 39, "Coaches": "M. Budenholzer (43-39)" }, { "idx": 6, "Season": "2015-16", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks*", "W": 48, "L": 34, "Coaches": "M. Budenholzer (48-34)" }, { "idx": 7, "Season": "2014-15", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks*", "W": 60, "L": 22, "Coaches": "M. Budenholzer (60-22)" }, { "idx": 8, "Season": "2013-14", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks*", "W": 38, "L": 44, "Coaches": "M. Budenholzer (38-44)" }, { "idx": 9, "Season": "2012-13", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks*", "W": 44, "L": 38, "Coaches": "L. Drew (44-38)" }, { "idx": 10, "Season": "2011-12", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks*", "W": 40, "L": 26, "Coaches": "L. Drew (40-26)" }, { "idx": 11, "Season": "2010-11", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks*", "W": 44, "L": 38, "Coaches": "L. Drew (44-38)" }, { "idx": 12, "Season": "2009-10", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks*", "W": 53, "L": 29, "Coaches": "M. Woodson (53-29)" } ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[(df['Coaches'].str.split('(').str[0] != df['Coaches'].shift(1).str.split('(').str[0]) | (df['Coaches'].str.split('(').str[0] != df['Coaches'].shift(-1).str.split('(').str[0])]
```

Output:

|  | idx | Season | Team | W | L | Coaches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2020-21 | Atlanta Hawks* | 41 | 31 | L. Pierce (14-20) N. McMillan (27-11) |
| 2 | 3 | 2018-19 | Atlanta Hawks | 29 | 53 | L. Pierce (29-53) |
| 3 | 4 | 2017-18 | Atlanta Hawks | 24 | 58 | M. Budenholzer (24-58) |
| 7 | 8 | 2013-14 | Atlanta Hawks* | 38 | 44 | M. Budenholzer (38-44) |
| 8 | 9 | 2012-13 | Atlanta Hawks* | 44 | 38 | L. Drew (44-38) |
| 10 | 11 | 2010-11 | Atlanta Hawks* | 44 | 38 | L. Drew (44-38) |
| 11 | 12 | 2009-10 | Atlanta Hawks* | 53 | 29 | M. Woodson (53-29) |

I wasn't sure what you whether you'd want to count Pierce/McMillan as the first mention of Pierce, my answer assumes so. If you want to count this as a separate hit, just replace `split('(')` with `rsplit('(', 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates` method.

```
comp = re.compile(r'[A-Z].\s\w+')
df['Coaches_Names'] = df['Coaches'].apply(lambda x: ' - '.join(comp.findall(x)))  # New column which includes only coache's names 
df['Team'] = df['Team'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(re.sub('\*', '', x)))   # Dropping '*' characters from name of teams
    
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Team', 'Coaches_Names'], inplace=True)

print(df)
     Season           Team   W   L   W/L%                                Coaches            Coaches_Names
0   2020-21  Atlanta Hawks  41  31  0.569  L. Pierce (14-20) N. McMillan (27-11)  L. Pierce - N. McMillan
1   2019-20  Atlanta Hawks  20  47  0.299                      L. Pierce (20-47)                L. Pierce
3   2017-18  Atlanta Hawks  24  58  0.293                 M. Budenholzer (24-58)           M. Budenholzer
8   2012-13  Atlanta Hawks  44  38  0.537                        L. Drew (44-38)                  L. Drew
11  2009-10  Atlanta Hawks  53  29  0.646                     M. Woodson (53-29)               M. Woodson
```

It is up to you to drop or not `Coaches_Names` Column.

Additionally, you can prefer to use `keep` parameter. It allows you to make selection on first or last year. For more information you can look at documents. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

###### EDIT

Code is editted to format columns, @RJ, Adriaansen

Comment: This won't work since the `Coaches` column contains more info than just the name.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through dataframe:

```
it = df.iterrows()  #get iterator
for index, row in it:

    # to delete row
    if cond:
        df.drop([row], inplace=True)

# reset indices if needed
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```